# Android Studio looks for older version of build tools

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

## Description

In Android Studio 3.0.1, after updating the Android build tools (installing 26.0.3 and 27.0.3) and removing the old version (26.0.2), a Gradle sync of any project without explicit build tools version fails with:

```
Error:Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.0.2
<a href="install.build.tools">Install Build Tools 26.0.2 and sync project</a>
```

This happens even for newly created projects. Supposedly, Android plugin for Gradle 3.0.1 uses the latest build tools version by default, but this doesn't appear to be the case.

## Question

How can I get AS to use the latest version by default for all projects?

I'd like to use the newer tools rather than getting stuck with 26.0.2. I can use the `android.buildToolsVersion` Gradle property in specific projects to get them to build, but this workaround is suboptimal. Cleaning a project or invalidating caches & restarting AS has no affect.

## System

- OS X 10.12.6
- AS 3.0.1, build AI-171.4443003
  build tools 26.0.3, 27.0.3
  plugins:

  - Gradle 171.4249.39
- JRE 1.8.0_152
- Gradle 4.1
- Android Plugin [for Gradle] 3.0.1

Comment: facing the same issue, kindly let me know if you got a solution ?

Comment: Same problem :( Did you found any solution?

Comment: @HussainSherwani: Comments are supposed to be used to request clarifications, provide constructive criticism, or suggest minor information, not to request help. Furthermore, if there had been an answer, you would see it below.

Comment: @RohitSharma: same.